# Updating Visual Studio 2015 extensions end up disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a machine with seems to repeat the following pattern with VS2015 (including all patches).

1. Install an extension and it's fine, works perfectly.
2. The developer of the extension releases a new update.
3. Update extension, which means VS2015 needs to be restarted.
4. Restart VS2015, look in the extensions and notice that the (updated) extension is now disabled.

I've tried clearing the MEF cache, but that doesn't seem to help. The only way I've found to resolve this is to

1. Delete the extension
2. Restart VS2015
3. Notice the extension is still there as disabled
4. Delete it again
5. Restart VS2015 (it's now removed)
6. Install the extension from fresh from the Extension manager.

I have another machine which doesn't experience this, and also the activity.xml file doesn't get updated unless there is a loading issue (where you get the error pop-up).

The first time I noticed this was when I installed Mads Kristensen's Web extensions pack (which included all of his components) and caused all the pre-installed components to be disabled, so I uninstalled that and deleted all the components that were bundled under that, as it looked like it didn't detect the component were already there and created a duplicate behind the scenes, but now it seems this is happening for all 3rd party components.

Has anyone got any ideas what I can try to resolve this and possibly what could be causing this?

I'm hoping there is a file somewhere in the VS folder that is logging the issue.

Comment: Same issue. I ended up here : [issue on github](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebExtensionPack/issues/4)

Answer (score 29):

I was having the same problem with VS2015 Community Update 3.

I found [this helpful tool on GitHub](https://github.com/remcoros/DuplicateExtensionFinder) via [this issue listing](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/issues/1959#issuecomment-231454835) (now closed)

I compiled and ran the little utility as instructed and it seems to have sorted the disabled extensions problem out for me.

Comment: No need to compile the tool, just [download it from the Releases page](https://github.com/remcoros/DuplicateExtensionFinder/releases). Be sure to allow access (file properties in Windows Explorer, then check the "Allow" check box).

Comment: I keep the utility handy as I've found I need to rerun it whenever I add/update extensions written by @mkristensen.

Comment: Also fixed issues with spurious upgrade notifications (the little 'flag' in the top right of Visual Studio.  (it takes a few seconds after VS launches, but it comes right.)

Answer (score 10):

The problem seems solved by:

1. Uninstall the extension
2. Restart VS
3. Uninstall the extension (it was still there!)
4. Restart VS
5. Install the extension

Now the extension seems to be enabled all the time :)

The answer copied from [Web Essentials disabled on VS 2015 start](https://github.com/nunit/docs/issues/141#issuecomment-259424941) issue on github.

Comment: I had to uninstall the extensions four or five times then finally disappeared.

Comment: I like this better than copying some binaries (or compiling) and running locally. +1 for including the reference to original answer!

Comment: I had a similar problem with the extension **Customize Visual Studio Window Title**. Your solution helped me - thanks!